# Wirecloud docker container exits just after restarting it

Tags: fiware, fiware-wirecloud

After installing wirecloud through this command :

```
$ docker run --name some-wirecloud -d -p 80:80 fiware/wirecloud:latest
```

Wirecloud is running without any problem. But when I reboot my computer
and restart the docker container of wirecloud through this command:
$ docker restart some-wirecloud
the docker container exits just after restarting:

```
$ docker container ps -a
```

> CONTAINER ID IMAGE COMMAND CREATED STATUS PORTS NAMES
>
> 61c5dedd1bc7 fiware/wirecloud:latest "/docker-entrypoin..." 3 days ago Exited (0) Less than a second ago some-wirecloud

When running start command, the docker exits as well. The result of the start commad is below:

```
$ docker start -a 61c5dedd1bc7
```

> Operations to perform:
>         Apply all migrations: admin, auth, catalogue, contenttypes, oauth2provider, platform, sessions
>
> Running migrations:
>         No migrations to apply.
>
> Found another file with the destination path 'theme/wirecloud.fiwarelabdarktheme/css/_variables.scss'. It will be ignored since only the first encountered file is collected. If this is not what you want, make sure every static file has a unique path.
>   Found another file with the destination path 'theme/wirecloud.fiwarelabdarktheme/css/header.scss'. It will be ignored since only the first encountered file is collected. If this is not what you want, make sure every static file has a unique path.
>   Found another file with the destination path 'theme/wirecloud.fiwarelabdarktheme/css/gadget.scss'. It will be ignored since only the first encountered file is collected. If this is not what you want, make sure every static file has a unique path.
>   Found another file with the destination path 'theme/wirecloud.fiwarelabdarktheme/css/wirecloud_core.scss'. It will be ignored since only the first encountered file is collected. If this is not what you want, make sure every static file has a unique path.
>   Found another file with the destination path 'theme/wirecloud.fiwarelabdarktheme/css/_variables.scss'. It will be ignored since only the first encountered file is collected. If this is not what you want, make sure every static file has a unique path.
>   Found another file with the destination path 'theme/wirecloud.fiwarelabdarktheme/images/favicon.ico'. It will be ignored since only the first encountered file is collected. If this is not what you want, make sure every static file has a unique path.
>   Found another file with the destination path 'theme/wirecloud.fiwarelabtheme/css/header.scss'. It will be ignored since only the first encountered file is collected. If this is not what you want, make sure every static file has a unique path.
>   Found another file with the destination path 'theme/wirecloud.fiwarelabtheme/css/gadget.scss'. It will be ignored since only the first encountered file is collected. If this is not what you want, make sure every static file has a unique path.
>   Found another file with the destination path 'theme/wirecloud.fiwarelabtheme/css/wirecloud_core.scss'. It will be ignored since only the first encountered file is collected. If this is not what you want, make sure every static file has a unique path.
>   Found another file with the destination path 'theme/wirecloud.fiwarelabtheme/css/_variables.scss'. It will be ignored since only the first encountered file is collected. If this is not what you want, make sure every static file has a unique path.
>   Found another file with the destination path 'theme/wirecloud.fiwarelabtheme/images/favicon.ico'. It will be ignored since only the first encountered file is collected. If this is not what you want, make sure every static file has a unique path.
>   Found another file with the destination path 'theme/wirecloud.fiwaretheme/css/header.scss'. It will be ignored since only the first encountered file is collected. If this is not what you want, make sure every static file has a unique path.
>   Found another file with the destination path 'theme/wirecloud.fiwaretheme/css/gadget.scss'. It will be ignored since only the first encountered file is collected. If this is not what you want, make sure every static file has a unique path.
>   Found another file with the destination path 'theme/wirecloud.fiwaretheme/css/wirecloud_core.scss'. It will be ignored since only the first encountered file is collected. If this is not what you want, make sure every static file has a unique path.
>   Found another file with the destination path 'theme/wirecloud.fiwaretheme/css/_variables.scss'. It will be ignored since only the first encountered file is collected. If this is not what you want, make sure every static file has a unique path.
>   Found another file with the destination path 'theme/wirecloud.fiwaretheme/images/logos/header.png'. It will be ignored since only the first encountered file is collected. If this is not what you want, make sure every static file has a unique path.
>
> 0 static files copied to '/opt/wirecloud_instance/static', 1167 unmodified.
>   Already up-to-date.
>   AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 172.17.0.5. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
>   httpd (pid 24?) not running
>   AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 172.17.0.5. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
>   httpd (pid 24) already running

What is the best way to manage restarting the docker container after rebooting the machine?

Answer (score 0):

Seems the problem is related to this [issue](https://github.com/Wirecloud/docker-wirecloud/issues/8). Moreover, it is very likely that you are the person who has reported the problem on github. In any case, the problem should be fixed on recent versions of the WireCloud images.